# jQuery: Calling a function from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, generic-handler

I'm trying to call a function when I get success from my ajax call, but it's not working. This is what I've tryed so far.

```
function dtMRPReasonCode(dt) {
    var data = null;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        url: "Index.aspx/getMRPReasonCodeReport",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.d) {
                console.log(dt);
                console.log(msg.d);
                buildTableBody(dt, msg.d);
            }
        },

        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Error: dtMRPReasonCode");
        }
    });

    return false;

}

function buildTableBody(dt, obj) {   
    dt.fnClearTable();
    data = [];

    $(obj).each(function(index, value) {
        element = [];

        element.push(value.Metric);
        element.push(value.Region);
        element.push(value.Plant);
        element.push(value.Customer);
        element.push(value.IMAC);
        element.push(value.NotFilled);
        element.push(value.Filled);
        element.push(value.Total);

        data.push(element);
    });

    dt.fnAddData(data);
}
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!

## Edit #1

I used `console.log` in order to show you what I got from `dt` and `msg.d` (Image)

## Edit #2

If I paste the commands from `buildTableBody` function in the `success:` handler instead of calling `buildTableBody` function in the `success:` handler it actually works:

```
function dtMRPReasonCode(dt) {
    var data = null;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        url: "Index.aspx/getMRPReasonCodeReport",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(msg) {
            dt.fnClearTable();
            data = [];

            $(msg.d).each(function(index, value) {
                element = [];

                element.push(value.Metric);
                element.push(value.Region);
                element.push(value.Plant);
                element.push(value.Customer);
                element.push(value.IMAC);
                element.push(value.NotFilled);
                element.push(value.Filled);
                element.push(value.Total);

                data.push(element);
            });

            dt.fnAddData(data); 
        },

        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Error: dtMRPReasonCode");
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

But it makes no sense to me, since this actually should work in both ways.

Comment: What are you getting? What tells you it's not working?

Comment: is it definitely coming back as success?

Comment: Isn't the `td` in your function call a typo? Apart from that, check your console for any errors.

Comment: In your `success()` function, where is `td` coming from?

Comment: @JonathanM: I got nothing, I believe that *buildTableBody* it's not being called.

Comment: could it be that `msg.d` is undefined so it never *enters* your `if` condition?

Comment: td should be dt it's a function parm

Comment: In `success` do an alert to show `td` and `msg.d`. Post your results here.

Comment: @DavidCheung: Yes it is.

Comment: @Styxxy: Yeah I've changed *td* to *dt*, and I also checked my console for error but I get nothing.

Comment: @JonathanM: If I do alert(msg.d) I get the whole information from my page method, If I do alert(dt) I get the datatable's reference.

Comment: Another general comment-  You seem to be POSTing an empty object to "get" data (getMRPReasonCodeReport)..   You really should be using HTTP GET instead.

Comment: @SteveH.: ASMX/ASPX will not return JSON data from a GET request http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: @BLSully, I'll add that to my list of reasons to shun ASMX/ASPX ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have a typo on your function call

```
buildTableBody(td, msg.d);
```

should be

```
buildTableBody(dt, msg.d);
```

Also what is the return type from `Index.aspx/getMRPReasonCodeReport`? If it is `string`, you've got to unescape the string before you can treat it as JSON.

Comment: In fact, it returns a generic list.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `contentType : "application/json utf-8"` from your AJAX call.  That is the type of the data sent to the server.  It is likely that you want the default content type.

Unless your server-side resource was configured to accept json it likely accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: ASPX/ASMX webservice methods need the contentType the OP provided when dealing with JSON serialization.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900231/asmx-webservice-not-returning-json-can-only-post-using-application-x-www-form-u

Comment: Interesting, I've only ever had success using `application/json; charset=utf-8` with ASMX

Comment: Im not 100% positive this is the issue here, but I have ran into this before.  It is hard to tell without seeing the server-side code/config etc, but its worth trying:)